# Yii2 Wait for queue to be empty

Tags: php, rest, yii, queue, codeception

I have a yii queue that uses db driver. I have a time consuming resource delete action in a controller. It pushes a job to the queue and returns success code to the caller.

I want to test this action by deleting a resource, waiting for the job to be complete, and confirming that deleted resource is not found anymore. Putting sleep() between DELETE and GET works, but instead I want to check whether the queue is empty of the jobs before making GET request.

I tried following: returning job_id from delete endpoint, and calling waitForQueueToBeEmpty($job_id) before sending GET request in tests.

```
public function waitForJobToBeEmpty($job_id) {
    while (!Yii::$app->queue->isDone($job_id));
}
```

This does not work, job never becomes done. I have my workers started.
What are my possibilities? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You push job and wait when it is done in the same process?

Comment: No, job gets pushed into queue on the endpoint after I send request from test. I then wait in test after receiving the response (which is always success).